# Placeholder is not displaying in IE for password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented the following scripts to display placeholders in IE for inputbox,but it is not working for password field ,Please advice me..

```
<script>
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
    test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
    });

    // Placeholder for IE
    $(function () {
        if(!$.support.placeholder) { 

            var active = document.activeElement;
            $(':text, textarea').focus(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            });
            $(':text, textarea').blur();
            $(active).focus();
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
            });
        }  

    });
</script>
```

Comment: seems very big code for a placeholder. you might want to browse this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19899531/1577396)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I didn't know it, but I learnt now.

Comment: i have **IE 10** and your code is working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `input[type="password"]` to your selector, so change:

```
$(':text, textarea')
```

to:

```
$(':text, textarea, input[type="password"]')
```

since **[:text selector](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)** only select `<input type="text">` elements

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You're not selecting password fields. The `:text` jQuery selector only selects `input`s that are `type=text` (either explicitly or implicitly). You'd have to add `input[type=passsword]` to your selector to also include password fields.
2. But once you fix that, you'll have the problem that, of course, the password field's value is displayed *obscured*. So setting your placeholder text on it won't show the placeholder. You'll have to show the placeholder text some other way, such as a `span` or `div` that you overlay on top of the field.